# Closing background JFrame after showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to write a very simple Blackjack game.

This is the class that is supposed to show the currently drawn card:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

public class ShowRandomCard {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

public void ShowUsARandomCard() {
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JLabel("A Panel"));
    f.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // Picture
    BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("somepicture"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    f.add(picLabel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // elements

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    Blackjack jt = new Blackjack();
    jt.dialog();

}

public void hideCards() {
    f.setVisible(false);
    f.remove(p);
    f.dispose();
    f.repaint();
}
}
```

And this is the actual game class:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class Blackjack {

    ShowRandomCard it = new ShowRandomCard();

   public void dialog() {

        int answer2 = showConfirmDialog(null, "some message", "some title",
                YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (answer2 == YES_OPTION) {
            garbageCollection();
            it.ShowUsARandomCard();
        if (answer2 == NO_OPTION || answer2 == CANCEL_OPTION) {
            garbageCollection();
        //  System.exit(0);
        }
        }
   }

public void garbageCollection() {
    it.hideCards();
}
 }
```

But the JPanel that holds the cards does not disappear.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: well i have tried my best to show only the essential parts

Comment: remember to call JFrame.redraw() after removing the card

Comment: I always get "The method redraw is undefined...". Tried with f.repaint(); but the panel is still shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove a component from a visible frame the basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

However, there is rarely a good reason to use code like that. Instead you should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to hide/show panels.

Method names do not start with an upper case character. "GarbageCollection()" should be `GarbageCollection()`

Comment: Unfortunately f.repaint(); has no effect. The panel still stays. Thank you for pointing out the name convention, overlooked it.

Comment: The revalidate() is the key, but again you completely ignored the proper solution which is to use a Card Layout. You still haven't posted a proper SSCCE, so I have no more help to offer.

Comment: No need for more help, revalidate was indeed the key. Thank you! Btw: have updated the code above, just for you ;-).